# gemfire start locator takes too long

Tags: java-8, gemfire, ubuntu-17.10, gfsh

I've installed gemfire in my Ubuntu 17.10, using the java version "1.8.0_161", and I'm trying to start a locator using gfsh.

`start locator --name=locator1`

After that it shows me the following message:

`Starting a Geode Locator in /home/john/projetos/my_gemfire/locator1...`

And it starts printing dots, lines and lines of dot:

`......................................................................`

I left once running and after hours it was still printing dots. It doesn't launch any error message, it just keep printing dots.

I saw a tutorial video about it, and there it just took seconds to really start the locator.

So, anyone could give an idea how could I solve that?

Comment: Does it have an option like `verbose` or something?

Comment: There's clearly something stuck during the startup... which GemFire version is this?, do you see any weird messages within the locator's logs?. What about thread dumps?, did you take several of them to see what each thread is doing?.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with Apache Geode 1.5 and open-jdk-9 on Ubuntu 16.04.4.

I found that the locator has been started because I can connect to it.

Press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to break out wait then use `connect` command to connect to a locator.

```
    dz@dz-ubuntu-16:~/my_geode$ gfsh
        _________________________     __
       / _____/ ______/ ______/ /____/ /
      / /  __/ /___  /_____  / _____  / 
     / /__/ / ____/  _____/ / /    / /  
    /______/_/      /______/_/    /_/    1.5.0

    Monitor and Manage Apache Geode
    gfsh>start locator --name=locator1
    Starting a Geode Locator in /home/dz/my_geode/locator1...
    ...................................................................................................................................................
    Broken out of wait... the Locator process will continue to startup in the background.


    gfsh>connect
    Connecting to Locator at [host=localhost, port=10334] ..
    Connecting to Manager at [host=192.168.2.168, port=1099] ..
    Successfully connected to: [host=192.168.2.168, port=1099]

    gfsh>start pulse
    Launched Geode Pulse
```

Actually your locator has been successfully started.